# 60s Short Story About AI Morality

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, artificial-intelligence

There was a 60s sci-fi short story where a partisan, who had been fighting tyranny on his home planet, manages to escape just before things fall apart. He had no choice but to leave his comrades behind.

As he sails into safety, he discusses his actions, and his ethical reckonings, with virtual reality encapsulations of each of the comrades, who all tell him he had no choice and did the right thing.

But eventually he has (actual) contact with one of them, who is livid that he'd abandoned them, and calls him an idiot for failing to realize that the virtual reality encapsulations of their personalities would, of course, tell him exactly what he wants to hear.